# VB application invoking & directing requests to web browser

Tags: http, browser, vb6, wininet

We've an existing application developed in VB 6.  There are 6 - 8 modules available. In main screen, a separate button is available for each module, which on click will load the respective modules.  We're in the process of migrating this to a web-enabled system and identified to go with Java-based solution.

Now instead of completely developing and migrating to Java platform, we're doing a technical feasibility study of migrating module-wise.  That is, on click of 'Module 1', for example, will open up a browser instead of existing VB application forms and all subsequent handling/processing/loading/saving will be handled by the web-based Java application, which actually runs on a web/app server. Slowly this will be migrated for other modules also.

My question is, is this technically possible/feasible? That is, can we open up a browser on click of a button and direct all subsequent requests, sessions, cookies to the Java application running on web/app server.  Any pointers/suggestions/thoughts towards this are really appreciated.

**NOTE:** I heard about WinINet API from my friends which enables to interact with HTTP protocols.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving to the "poor client" (Web) model then your back end will be creating 100% of the user interface as Web pages.

In such a case your existing rich client needs to be dumbed down.  There is no point in trying to request the HTML from the server and reinterpreting it into a rich user interface written in VB6.

Thus you don't need to worry about the WinInet API (which you wouldn't need anyway since from Win2K onward you have at least 3 very nice wrapper ActiveX controls and classes at your disposal: the Internet Transfer Control, the XmlHttpRequest class, and the WinHttpRequest class).

No, in your case you will probably be stuck with replacing your "modules" (???) which probably means Forms (?) by a Form hosting a WebBrowser control.

However it will be clumsy to integrate what goes on in there with your other "modules."  If that's needed you're going to probably need to spelunk the WebBrowser DOM to fish out data, inject data, etc.

Ideally you'd be moving to a Web Service model instead of a Web model.  This opens a world of front end possibilities (Web, mobile, rich client) without the need for multiple back ends and is quite usable in VB6.  Things have even gotten *easier* over time as SOAP is abandoned in favor of simpler, loosely-coupled RESTful Web Services.

What you have described is feasible to a degree, but when you start adding requirements like session cookie control it might get ugly.  You may end up needing two logons in your program, one for the old/existing parts and another for the browser-based parts.

You might be better off just letting part go over to a browser and strip parts out of the old app and make people run both side by side.